# WordPress get tags for Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, custom-post-type

Trying to get the tags for a custom post type called public-blob but the code is only pulling in the tags for a single blog post not all the public-blog cpt.

code is:

```
$posttags = get_the_tag_list();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {

    echo '<a href="' . get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) .'">' . $tag->name . '</a>'; 
  }
}
```

any help will be great.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the function [`get_the_term_list()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list) this function is like `get_the_tag_list()` but let you set your taxonomy.

Btw the function `get_the_tag_list()` and `get_the_term_list()` not return you an array you should set the before, separator, and after in the function.